# Dual boot installation order

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, bootloader

I am going to be testing Windows 10, so I want to set up a triple boot system, Windows 8, Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Its been a very long time since I've done this so I want to get some advice as to what order to install the Operating Systems so that I don't end up with the Windows 10 boot menu. Do I just install the OS with the boot loader I want to use last?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is not possible to add Ubuntu to the Windows own Bootloader to boot it (correct my if I'm wrong). To run Ubuntu you end up using GRUB. To save you work you should install Windows 8 and 10 first, then Ubuntu and let GRUB detect those two OS.

You can however first install Ubuntu then Ubuntu. But then you will need to update GRUB.

Comment: You actually can add a Ubuntu entry to the Win8 bootloader with help of EasyBCD, though I'm not sure with the Win10 bootloader.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know that. Yet I still think letting GRUB handle that would be still easier.

Comment: Yes GRUB would be easier. Doing it using Windows bootloader would require a reboot upon choosing Ubuntu since Windows files are loaded first. I do it because it looks beautiful :)